# TeamCity - Missing 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've been browsing around StackOverflow exploring possible solutions to my issue. For some reason TeamCity is unable to find 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' but I have installed all the required .Net packages. However, I've ran all the tests locally and building the project within Visual Studio returns a successful build.

This is the error which I am experiencing:

> App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs(9, 40): error CS0234: The type or namespace name  'DynamicModuleHelper' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**Solutions I have tried**

1. Within Visual Studio I was instructed by one StackOverflow thread to set the reference 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' option 'Copy Local' to true. This returned the same result of the error above.
2. I've deleted all references of 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' and performed a fresh install of this package, I'd had also reinstalled Ninject as well. I didn't specify a particular version. Again, building locally was successful remotely not so much - same error occurred.

Has anyone encountered such issue before? I had also done a fresh clone of the GIT Repository, restored all the NuGet Packages (Which TeamCity does as well) and it built completely fine.

Comment: Have you done a full clean and build after deleting everything in your packages folder, and verified that it gets pulled down from nuget via the build output window? Reason I'm asking is that I tend to fall into that particular pit of "hell, it works on my machine" when there was a lingering dll somewhere.

Comment: After asking this question I thought just that, I've instructed TeamCity to completely wipe it's cache folders of the project and do a fresh clone every build. At the same time - I hadn't performed another build at this point - I noticed the server was running VS Professional instead of VS Ultimate. So I swapped the VS, re-ran the build and what do you know. It built!

Answer (score 1):

After asking this question I'd continued my investigation. While my continuous integration server is running multiple windows virtual machines, and since TeamCity load balances the builds across these virtual machines some of their configurations were out of sync with the rest. Some of the team code purely in C++, so the version of Microsoft Visual Studio which was installed (Visual Studio Professional 2013) was the incorrect version for my C# project. After attempting to open the project with Visual Studio on one of the selected VM's, I found that Visual Studio didn't understand the csproj file extension.

I installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate - this is version I use on my workstation - and thankfully it complied. sometimes within my project, when I request a build it would use older files as TeamCity would cache the files locally. I found setting the to 'clean and re-download' within the VCS options also remedied this issue.